How to keep aluminum door from opening when it does not have a handle on the outside and won't stay shut when pulled closed
We have recently moved to Spain into a rental property and for some reason they do not have door handles on the outside of patio doors (a number of the properties we looked at as we were preparing to move had this same setup.)
It is a nice set of aluminum double doors with only a handle on the inside. The door can easily be opened and can also tilt to allow ventilation. The problem arises when someone goes out to the patio (to grill for instance) and there is no handle on the outside of the door so they cannot close the door behind them.
We added a suction cup handle, suctioned to the glass, which works well enough to pull the door shut, but there is no latch. I was able to jerry rig a stick using the suction cup handle to keep the door shut, but that means the door cannot be open from the inside. (Quite a pain for the rest of my family - and a total pain if the hands of the person outside are full.)
I have considered door latch magnets, but the clearances around the frame are such that I can't figure out a good way to mount them or how to orient them. I was thinking a ball door catch, but again, I do not have enough space in the frame (not deep enough) to install the ball or clearance to install the strike plate.
I have also thought about a 3d printed door latch with a passthrough rod so the door latch can be operated from both the inside and the outside. I've not found good designs for this, and I am concerned the 3D printed material will not be strong enough.
My searches on the internet have not been fruitful - with the most common result is to use a wedge... which obviously would not work in my situation. I am really scratching my head to figure out a solution. Please help!





Do the doors slide or swing?  How do you lock them at night? They tilt!?   I'm confused.  May be a pic from farther away so we can see the whole situation.

The doors swing. The handle on the inside cannot be operated from the outside, so there is no need to lock. They tilt forward from the bottom (making a V-shape if you look at it from the side) These types of doors are quite common in Europe.
If you turn the handle up 90 degrees, it swings open like a regular door, if you swing the handle up 180 degrees it tilts towards you.

I have the door scheme you gave. Go to a glass shop. Most manufacturers have exterior handles and spring loaded latches that are mounted into the existing tracks that solve this exact problem. Look carefully at the hardware for a manufacturers stamp and go from there.

If you can't (or are unwilling to) drill and change out the latch/handle hardware for a common in-swing door handleset, you could try a simple surface-mount spring catch. Their function is simple: when you close the door by pulling from the outside (or pushing from the inside), the arm pivots and holds the door in position by spring tension. To open it again (from either side) one just needs enough pull/push with enough force to overcome the spring, and the catch opens and resets for the next use. These are common and should be available at any good hardware store (and of course, from ubiquitous on-line retailer...)


Unfortunately, there is no space to install such a device - the door is tight around the frame and to the other leaf.
The door is a multi-point latch, where the latches move up and down when you turn the handle, and there is no sprung mechanism to retain the latches before they are secured behind a plate when you turn the handle either down to lock or up to vent the top.

There is actually no space on the outside of the door for a door handle (it was one of my first thoughts to replace the handle and install one on the outside,) however the handle is literally almost on the edge, and relies on a spring loaded pusher pushing against a strike plate to unblock the turning of the handle. I have not found a replacement door handle set which could possibly be installed in its place.
I took some additional photos which show the latches in the door which move up and down with the handle, and on the jamb side they slide behind the plate. https://imgur.com/a/lPwYANU

You can mount this to the other door.
